# VB.NET 2015 - Save DataGridView as .ini File

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have a project of loading an excel file to a DataGridView and then save that DataGridView data to a ".ini" file. So, Since I am very new to VB.net i would like your help.

This is my code. I have managed to read the Excel file in a DataGridView and save it as text file. I can't understand from the tutorials how to save it as a ini file. I need help... Thank all of you.

```
Imports System
Imports System.IO
Imports Microsoft.Win32

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        If TextBox1.Text = "password" Then
            Form2.Show()
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Please Enter The Correct Password", "Information")
        End If
        Try
                Dim MyConnection As OleDb.OleDbConnection
                Dim Ds As System.Data.DataSet
                Dim MyAdapter As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
                MyConnection = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='C:\Users\Pratto_lp3\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\SCHEDULE.xlsx';Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;'")
                MyAdapter = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from [S-BOTTOM_(1)$]", MyConnection)
                Ds = New System.Data.DataSet
                MyAdapter.Fill(Ds)
                Me.DataGridView1.DataSource = Ds.Tables(0)
            Catch ex As Exception
                'MsgBox(ex.Message)
                MsgBox("ExcelFile File Loaded")
            End Try


    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        If (FolderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK) Then
            TextBox1.Text = FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click

        Dim writer As TextWriter = New StreamWriter("c:\users\pratto_lp3\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\DtgrdToText.ini")

        For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 2 Step +1
            For j As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1 Step +1
                writer.Write(vbTab & DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value.ToString & vbTab & "|")
            Next
            writer.WriteLine("")
            writer.WriteLine("....................................")
        Next
        writer.Close()
        MessageBox.Show("Data Saved")

        'Dim result As String = ""
        ''go through all rows
        'For rownumber As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
        '    'this gets just column 0 (the first column)
        '    result &= DataGridView1.Rows(rownumber).Cells("f10").Value & vbCrLf
        '    'result += datagridview1.item(0, rownumber).tostring
        'Next
        ''write out the string
        'File.WriteAllText("c:\users\pratto_lp3\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\datagrid1", result)
        'MessageBox.Show("file saved")
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: If you just need to create a file, then File.WriteAllText is probably what you need.

Comment: what you expect to have in that ini file? please give an example how those rows/columns data should be placed on the ini file

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply.But what i need is the data inside to the datagridview to save them in a way like this For example:

[Dimension]
Length=12
height=2

[Wires]
Cross=50
Long=15
etc.

I read orders for mesh panels from excel file,i put into a datagridview and then i need to save the data like this to ini file and send them to the controler. Thats the main idea.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Dim writer As System.IO.StreamWriter
writer = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter("c:\users\pratto_lp3\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\DtgrdToText.ini", True)

For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 2 Step +1
    For j As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1 Step +1
        writer.Write(vbTab & DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value.ToString & vbTab & "|")
    Next
    writer.WriteLine("")
    writer.WriteLine("....................................")
Next
writer.Close()
MessageBox.Show("Data Saved")
```

Answer (score 0):

the datagridview is bidimensional, have row and colums.
your result must be:

```
[row1]
col1=some data
col2=soma data

[row2]
col1=some data1
col2=soma data2
```

this is your aim?

Comment: could you please help me in any way?

Answer (score 0):

ok, try this:

```
Dim writer As System.IO.StreamWriter
    writer = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter("c:\users\pratto_lp3\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\DtgrdToText.ini", True)

    For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 2 Step +1
        'write row
        writer.WriteLine(String.Format("[row{0}]", i))
        For j As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1 Step +1
            'write columns title and value
            writer.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}={1}", DataGridView1.Columns(j).Name, DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value.ToString))
        Next
        writer.WriteLine(String.Empty)
    Next
    writer.Close()
```

Comment: Perfext.Thank you.The above worked well.But it also shows empty cells which are lots of them.Maybe i have to make an if statement inorder to check for empty cells and show only those that have data inside

Comment: You're welcome, you can extend the code with any control on the data.